# Is it possible to make procedural low poly grass?

Tags: modeling, objects, particles

To preface, I'm very new to Blender and only really know the basics!

Anyhow, like the title says, I want to add some grass onto a [little scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dY2Tb.png) I'm making. I learned a little bit about it through tutorials like this [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f76Jc54tjrg), but I didn't really know how to implement it onto the ground I made! The result looked nice, however, I also didn't know how to rotate the individual groups of blades better either.

Is there any way to do this procedurally so it wouldn't be too taxing? Or is there another way I could achieve the same result? I just want a little cartoony grass is all!

Comment: Cute little scene. He pretty much explained everything in his video. I've watched in fast forward, but he showed how to add grass particles on a plane (happens at 01:57), then how to rotate each of the groups randomly (he ticked "advance" in the particle system to make the "rotation" submenu appears).

Comment: I see! Would it be possible to have that exact same setup on the top portion of the ground I made then rather than on planes? Or would I need to go about the same method a little differently?

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)